# How to read from file in Big or Lower Endian format in Python

Tags: python, matlab, io, binary, endianness

I am trying to update a script from Matlab to Python and am having trouble with a single section. The code is supposed to read a binary file and translate it into something I can use to make plots.

The MatLab code I am having trouble with is this:

```
%reopen the data file using the correct HIFIRST/LOFIRST format

if COMM_ORDER==0
   fid=fopen(fn,'r','ieee-be');   %HIFIRST
else
   fid=fopen(fn,'r','ieee-le');    %LOFIRST
end;
```

This is not originally my code, so I am having trouble knowing what to do in Python and I have not been able to find an answer yet using Google (shocker, right?).

It may be that I am understanding it wrong, but I think it's only looking to reformat the file endianness, not to actually *read* the file itself. I later use fid.seek() and a.fromfile() (where a=array.array('h' or 'b' or 'l' or 'd')) that draws from the file, not a data array.

MatLab fread:

```
function b=ReadByte(fid, Addr)
fseek(fid,Addr,'bof');
b=fread(fid,1,'int8');

function w=ReadWord(fid, Addr)
fseek(fid,Addr,'bof');
w=fread(fid,1,'int16');
```

And so on to:

```
function d=ReadDouble(fid, Addr)
fseek(fid,Addr,'bof');
d=fread(fid,1,'float64');
```

These functions have already been translated to python using:

```
def ReadByte(fid, Addr):
fid.seek(Addr,0)
    a=array.array('b')
    a.fromfile(fid,1)
b=a[0]
    return b

def ReadWord(fid, Addr):
fid.seek(Addr,0)
    a=array.array('h')
    a.fromfile(fid,1)
w=a[0]
    return w
```

Down to:

```
def ReadDouble(fid, Addr):
fid.seek(Addr,0)
    a=array.array('d')
    a.fromfile(fid,1)
d=a[0]
    return d
```

Would it be better to continue with only files like I have already done? Or should I attempt to change the code into working with arrays instead of from the file? I am at a loss here.

Comment: This doesn't change the endianness, it specifies which endianness to use when reading the file. `fid` is likely used later to read from the file. It's not clear what reading from those files has anything to do with arrays.

Comment: fid is used in fid.seek() and then the binary is read in 8 bit, 16 bit, etc. increments as integers into an array. This array is then used to make plots of the data. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: You have to show the lines of the Matlab code following the file opening, where you have the actual `fread` instructions and put that into your post. From the comments it looks like you'll have to read 16bits (2-byte) values but we really need to see the relevant lines of code to be sure.

Comment: @Hoki Like this? (editted above)

Comment: Yes, at least we know you have to read _multi-byte_ values sometimes. The `be` or `le` setting when opening file in Matlab does not change anything in the file itself, it just tells the computer how to [interpret multi byte values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) at each `fread` operation. My knowledge of Python is too poor to answer, but I suggest you change your question title to "**How to read from file in Big or Lower Endian format in Python**", or something of this kind.

Comment: @ Hoki I changed the title, but I'm not sure how that will help get an answer. I did a few tests with a shorter file I wrote myself to see how the {be} or {le} changed how it was read, but it appeared to give the same answer. :/ I am wondering if I even need it in the first place or if its for a 'just in case'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a few days of digging around, I found a similar code to do what I wanted and used it as an example. The code can be found [here](http://qtwork.tudelft.nl/gitdata/users/guen/qtlabanalysis/analysis_modules/general/lecroy.py).

Comment: The link is broken! better to post the code here